# How to use a dyn Trait and still keep parallel performance in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, rayon

To practice Rust I'm implementing a raytracer.

First step I only implemented it only using spheres. I would loop over a Vector of Sphere structs.
I could easily increase performance using `rayon`  by doing `into_iter_par`.

Now I'm trying to add cubes. So instead of looping over `Vec<Sphere>` I'm looping over `Vec<Box<dyn Body>>`. This seems to negate the performance gained by using rayon.

How is this performance loss happening and I can I fix it?

In this code snippet I can reproduce the behavior.

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::f64::consts::PI;
use std::time::Instant;

pub trait Body: Sync + Send {
    fn size(&self) -> f64 {
        0.
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Sphere {
    radius: f64,
}

impl Sphere {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Sphere { radius: 4.0 }
    }
}

impl Body for Sphere {
    fn size(&self) -> f64 {
        4.0 / 3.0 * PI * self.radius * self.radius * self.radius
    }
}
pub struct World {
    bodies: Vec<Box<dyn Body>>,
    spheres: Vec<Sphere>,
}

impl World {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut world = World {
            bodies: vec![],
            spheres: vec![],
        };
        for _ in 0..100000000 {
            world.spheres.push(Sphere::new());
            world.bodies.push(Box::new(Sphere::new()));
        }
        world
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("Creating structs");
    let world = World::new();
    println!("Normal,Spheres");
    let timer = Instant::now();
    world.spheres.iter().map(|s| s.size()).sum::<f64>();
    println!("elapsed time:{:?}", timer.elapsed());

    println!("Normal,Bodies");
    let timer = Instant::now();
    world.bodies.iter().map(|s| s.size()).sum::<f64>();
    println!("elapsed time:{:?}", timer.elapsed());

    println!("Parallel,Spheres");
    let timer = Instant::now();
    world.spheres.into_par_iter().map(|s| s.size()).sum::<f64>();
    println!("elapsed time:{:?}", timer.elapsed());

    println!("Parallel,Bodies");
    let timer = Instant::now();
    world.bodies.into_par_iter().map(|s| s.size()).sum::<f64>();
    println!("elapsed time:{:?}", timer.elapsed());
}
```

When running with the release build, this produces the output:

```
Creating structs
Normal,Spheres
elapsed time:97ns
Normal,Bodies
elapsed time:323.960404ms
Parallel,Spheres
elapsed time:88.960257ms
Parallel,Bodies
elapsed time:6.015788183s
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this performance issue. After several attempts with different number of spheres/bodies, I couldn't really tell the difference between iterating over `Vec<Sphere>` or `Vec<Box<dyn Body>>`. Besides, I get almost the same values when iterating parallelly or not.

Comment: Just to make sure you are compiling with `cargo build --release` right?

Comment: The output and measurement are from a release build

Comment: Which performance gain? 97ns is way faster than 88.9ms.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the sum, so the first one is being completely optimized out. You need to do something with it, such as printing:

```rs
let sum = world.spheres.iter().map(|s| s.size()).sum::<f64>();
println!("elapsed time:{:?} ({sum})", timer.elapsed());
```

This benchmark is meaningless.

1. You're not performing the calculation you are trying to optimize (raytracing). You can't benchmark raytracing by benchmarking a sum.
2. Raytracers are typically parallel over pixels, not objects. You might be able to make a rasterizer parallel over objects, but it makes little sense for a raytracer.
3. You aren't comparing equivalent operations. Using `Box<dyn Body>` *will* be slower, but it allows you to store different objects, which you aren't utilizing. Compare it with storing an enum, or storing different object types in different `Vec`s.
4. The parallel equivalent of `iter` is `par_iter`. Using `into_par_iter` will also drop the items, which is likely taking more time than the sum.

Comment: Instead of actually using the return value you could also pass it into [`black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.black_box.html) which is designed to disable such optimizations.